# clear Safari cache from script

Tags: macos, safari

Here is a Python script that clears cookies from Safari (OS X):

```
from Foundation import *
store = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
L = store.cookies()
print len(L)
for c in L:
    store.deleteCookie_(c)
print len(store.cookies())
```

Is there a similar API to clear Safari's Cache and LocalStorage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the cache, you would be looking at `NSURLCache` and the method(s) `removeAllCachedResponses` and `removeCachedResponseForRequest`

For the LocalStorage, there does not appear to be an API for talking directly to Safari LocalStorage except through JS.

I did find this AppleScript however which basically circumvents the API and deletes the SQLite databases directly, obviously replace USERNAME with your username.

tell application "Finder"

```
select every item of folder "LocalStorage" of folder "Safari" of folder "Library" of folder "USERNAME" of folder "Users" of startup disk
move selection to the trash
end tell
```

Finally, there's a project on SourceForge called [SafariCleaner](http://sourceforge.net/projects/safaricleaner/) which does all that you are trying to do in a set of AppleScripts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I explored this more at length here:  http://telliott99.blogspot.com/2012/04/ive-been-annoyed-with-safari-for-while.html.